# Switch css files dynamically

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#

I am trying to switch CSS files dynamically in ASP.Net using C#.

When I click on Button1/ button2 the code is working fine and the CSS file is switching on/off, but when I open another page the CSS is deactivated.

When I refresh the page the CSS file is also deactivated.

example>     home (deafault) ! About us ! contact us

When I click on `about us`, another page opens, the CSS file becomes deactivated and default one activated.

I want the CSS file to not be deactivated if I click on `about us` after switching the CSS file.

Please advise me.

### Below is the code I have written in the master page

```
<head>
<link id="lnkCSS" runat="server" href = "~/css/main-style.css.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<form>    
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="CSS 1" OnClick="ChangeCSS" CommandArgument="theme1.css" />

    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="CSS 2" OnClick="ChangeCSS" CommandArgument="theme2.css" />   
</form>
```

### Below is the code I have written

```
protected void ChangeCSS(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lnkCSS.Attributes["href"] = "~/CSS/" + (sender as Button).CommandArgument;
}
```

Regards

Comment: You need to save it somewhere that option, maybe on a cookie, or on session, or on user settings if you have registered users.

Comment: Try to add them into different panels, show or hide them with panel visible property. or you can use updatepanel so that your page doesn't reload even you click on other link etc.

Comment: And this is about SQL Server how?

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a post back (or partial) to retain the currently selected CSS. This will allow other pages to load the currently selected CSS over the default.